# how to customize x axis in xts plot

Tags: r, xts, axis-labels, candlestick-chart

Following from this topic  [How do I set width of candles in candle chart using plot.xts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443093/how-do-i-set-width-of-candles-in-candle-chart-using-plot-xts) , I have noticed how `plot.xts` creates such fantastic candlestick plot. However when I tried the codes from that post I cannot get the x axis right. 
I tried

```
start <- as.Date('2007-01-03');end<-as.Date('2007-12-31')
from.dat <- start;to.dat <- end
getSymbols("C", src="yahoo", from = from.dat, to = to.dat)
candlecolors <- ifelse(C[,'C.Close'] < C[,'C.Open'], 'RED', 'GREEN')
plot.xts(C, type='candles',width=70000, candle.col=candlecolors,     bar.col='BLACK',cex.axis=1.5,main='Candlestick plot of Citigroup (2007)',cex.main=2)
```

The x axis isn't as I desired. I need something similar to the coloured plot from this post 
[How do I set width of candles in candle chart using plot.xts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443093/how-do-i-set-width-of-candles-in-candle-chart-using-plot-xts)

Sorry I haven't got enough reputation to post images. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Long

Answer (score 1):

The plotting parameter `xaxt` can be passed to `plot.xts()`. So the first thing you can do is add the argument `xaxt="n"` to your `plot.xts()` call. This will tell R not to automatically draw an axis.

You can then call `axis()` multiple times, once for each color of tick mark. Read up on the documentation for that function, it's pretty straightforward. If you're stuck, here's a short thread from the R-help archive with a solution:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/axis-tick-colors-only-one-value-allowed-td4188284.html.

On the other hand there might be a better solution somewhere in the `xts` package.